# How do you add a series of vertical lines to date axis in amCharts 5

Tags: amcharts5

Can someone please give an example of setting the a vertical line series correctly in amCharts 5 specifcally. There aren't any examples out there (that I have found) for what I am looking for.
I want to mark specific dates on a price chart with simple vertical lines.

I have tried amCharts 5 documentation but I can't find an example to work from.